# Vectos additions give "line"

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^2$ linearly independent vectors and $v>0$ (meaning its two components are positive).

I am a bit confused about the formulation that in this case the *line* 
$$
v+sw, ~~-\infty <s<+\infty
$$
must intersect at least one of the positive axes, say at $u=v+sw$.

(1) First of all what is meant by *line*. For me $v+sw$ is a vector starting in the origin for each $s$.

(2) I guess since $v>0$, we can always find an $s$ such that the vector $u=v+sw$ is a multiple of $e_1=(1,0)$ or $e_2=(0,1)$. I think this is meant with "must intersect at least one of the positive axes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) In this case $v+sw$ is referencing the point where that vector starting in the origin you mentioned ends. Doing that for all s gives you a line with the same slope as the slope of $w$ through the point $v$ (again, meaning the end of the vector $v$ starting at the origin.

(2) Yes, your line has a point in the first quadrant, so it must cross at least one positive axis (including $(0, 0)$). If you didn't have that condition $v>0$, you might have a line given by $(-1,0)+s(1,0)$, which is a vertical line through the point $(-1,0)$, so it doesn't cross the y-axis at all and the x-axis only on the negative side.

Mathematically, your attempt is correct. You can always solve $v+sw=(x,0)$ for $s$ and then $x$. If $x \geq 0$, you got your intersection point, otherwise you can prove that solving $v+sw=(0,y)$ results in $y \geq 0$.

Comment: "prigin"? Also, $w$ is not the slope. The slope is, if anything, $\frac{w_1}{w_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The line is meant as the set $$L=\{v+sw| s\in\mathbb R\}$$

which is the set of **all** vectors of the form $v+sw$. So, the line contains the point (or vector) $v$, but also the point $v+w$, and $v+2w$, and $v+\pi v$, and $v+\frac e\pi v$ and so on.

(2) By "the line must intersect at least one of the positive axes", what is meant is that the intersection of $L$ and the set $\{(x,0)| x\geq0\}$ or the set $\{(0,y)|y\geq0\}$ is non-empty.

Comment: The sets should include $(0,0)$. Otherwise the statement doesn't hold.

Comment: @PattuX You're right, fixed.